# Error 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

Tengo un pequeño sistema hecho en `Laravel` y hosteado en `Azure`, el problema es que en los últimos días me ha arrojado un ERROR 500 Internal Server Error.

Este es el error:

```
[Sat Aug 03 10:54:57.209547 2019] [core:error] [pid 98237] [client ip] End of script output before headers: index.php 
[Sat Aug 03 10:55:09.555597 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 100208] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client ip] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server 
[Sat Aug 03 10:55:09.555637 2019] [core:error] [pid 100208] [client ip] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

¿Tienen alguna sugerencia para resolver este error?

Comment: El log de dice que tienes un error en `index.php`. Nos puedes mostrar el contenido de este script?

Comment: No es el index, es mas a nivel de apache.

Comment: ¿Ya comprobaste que tengas los permisos adecuados?, la carpeta de tu proyecto debería de tener los permisos 755, al igual que la carpeta bootstrap y storage.

Comment: En realidad eso pense, incluso le llegue a poner 777.

Answer (score 2):

Hola Lo he resuelto levemente, procedo a explicar lo que hice:

Cambien los permisos a 775, fui al Cpanel y Cambien la version de PHP de 7.2 a 7.1.

Después de eso me funciono.

Answer (score 2):

Yo tuve el mismo probelma al clonar un repositorio en homestead y esta fue mi solución.

El primer paso fue instalar composer

> composer install

Después cambiar el nombre del .env.example por .env

> mv .env.example .env

limpiar cache

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> composer dump-autoload

y por último generar el key

> php artisan key:generate

Yo obtuve la información de este video:
https://youtu.be/2PHsbIS66H4

¡Espero y esta información les sirva, saludos!.

Comment: Buen día, la respuesta está en un idioma diferente al oficial en el sitio "StackOverflow en español" te recomiendo que edites tu respuesta y la pongas en el idioma correcto. Tal como está, tu respuesta podría ser votada de forma negativa.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, no me había  percatado que estaba en la página en español.

Answer (score 0):

No sabia donde aplicar los permisos asi que encontre esto:

> /opt/lampp/htdocs$ sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_app
>
> /opt/lampp/htdocs$ sudo chmod -R 777 laravel_app/storage

luego de aplicar estos comandos si es necesario reinicia tu servidor.

fuente:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42313680/11535769